# Binomial in relation to the Harmonic number

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j}{2k \choose j}^2+\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j}{2k \choose j}=H_{2k}$$

Where $H_k$; [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

Comment: The conjectured identity you posted is incorrect. Assuming this is just a typo, perhaps you meant to write: $$\sum_{j=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} {2k \choose j}^2+\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j}{2k \choose j}=H_{2k}$$
Also there is no context to your question. What have you tried? Have you tried substituting for ${2k \choose j}$ using factorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{2k}\binom{2k}{j}e^{-ij\theta}=(1+e^{-i\theta})^{2k}-1, $$
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j}\binom{2k}{j}(e^{ij\theta}-1)=\int_{0}^{\theta}\left[(1-e^{i\varphi})^{2k}-1\right]\,d\varphi, $$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j}\binom{2k}{j}^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\theta}\left[(1-e^{i\varphi})^{2k}-1\right]\cdot\left[(1+e^{-i\theta})^{2k}-1\right]\,d\varphi\,d\theta$$
and the problem boils down to integrating $(1-e^{i\varphi}+e^{-i\theta}-e^{i(\varphi-\theta)})^{2k}$ over $0\leq\varphi\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$.
Additionally
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{2k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j}\binom{2k}{j}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=1}^{2k}\binom{2k}{j}(-1)^j x^{j-1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-(1-x)^{2k}}{x}\,dx $$
equals
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2k}}{1-x}\,dx = H_{2k} $$
hence the claim appears to be a consequence of the binomial transform or the residue theorem.